# how to create a table inside plugin in wordpress database

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a table in existing wordpress database.and i am unable to create it . I have write this code inside a custom plugin files.Please help me through this code.

```
<?php
/**
* @package Demo
*/
/*
Plugin Name: Demo
Plugin URI: https://demo.com/
Description: This is used for the plugin database.
Version: 3.2
Author: Automattic
Author URI: https://automattic.com/wordpress-plugins/
License: GPLv2 or later
Text Domain: demo
*/
// run the install scripts upon plugin activation
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'your_plugin_options_install');

// function to create the DB / Options / Defaults                   
function your_plugin_options_install() {
global $wpdb;
global $db_version;

$your_db_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'db_record';
// create the ECPT metabox database table

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $your_db_name . " (
    `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `field_1` mediumtext NOT NULL,
    `field_2` tinytext NOT NULL,
    `field_3` tinytext NOT NULL,
    `field_4` tinytext NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY id (id)
    );";

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
    add_option("db_version", $db_version);

    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     function wpa_install() {

    /*Create Table on Plugin Activation*/
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "table_name"; 
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name  (
            `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                
            `records` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
            `loggedin_time` datetime NOT NULL,
            `unique_number` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
           ) $charset_collate"; 

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );
    /*Create Table on Plugin Activation*/

}


    class WP_DiscoverU {

// Constructor
function __construct() 

    register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, array($this, 'wpa_uninstall'));
    //call function when activate plugin
   }
}
```

Above code for generate table when activate plugin.

Comment: I don't know why but i am unable to create a table in wordpress database for a long while, even it's not showing any error . I have tried nearly all the solution which is available on internet.can you help to get this problem?

Comment: let me know when you add plugin that plugin show in wordpress admin panel if "Yes" , when you active plugin any error display if no any error occur when activate plugin add Above code and again deactivate and activate (bacause this code execute when activate plugin)

Please Try this.

Comment: i have already said that it's not showing any error.but unable to display the table in database